# Can you help me explain this piece of code

Tags: java

I understand the charAt part, but the other part i'm having some trouble with. The rest of this code can you explain this to me step by step, so i understand it more clearly.  Thanks

```
public static boolean y(String str) {
    int i = 0;
    int j = str.length()-1;
    while (i != j && (j - i) != 1) {
        if (str.charAt(i) != str.charAt(j)) 
        {
            return false;
        }
        i++;
        j--;
    }
    return true;
}
```

opps i made an error the while statement is suppose to be this >> while (i != j && (j - 1) ! = 1)

Comment: What's this: `!= !`? Does it compile?

Comment: Consider creating a table with the variables on top and one row for each step. Then, in each row, note down the variable contents for each next step in the code. You will automatically learn what the program does :)

Comment: @Keyser: surely that check is performed by i != j?

Comment: @DavidGrant Yes, I just realized that myself :p It needs to check that  `i < j` though.

Comment: Why halt the loop when `j - i == 1`?  If you have a even length string, you will halt prematurely.

Answer (score 5):

The code will determine whether or not `str` is a palindrome.

`i` will represent each character from the beginning to the middle of the string.  `j` will represent each character from the end to the middle of the string.

You initialise `i` by setting the value to 0 (the first character).  `j` is initialised to be the length of the string minus 1 (the last character).

Your code then loops, comparing the characters represented by `i` and `j` until they don't match, or until there are no characters left to compare.

For example, given the palindrome "radar`, the code could compare:

- r with r
- a with a

and then terminate.  In odd-length palindromes, there is obviously no need to compare the middle character, hence the `i != j` in your `while` statement.

You have a problem in your code when dealing with even-length palindromes.  `i` and `j` will cross-over, but never be the same.  The second clause, `(j - i) != 1`, appears to be designed to fix this, but it makes the comparison too soon!

Given the palindrome, "pullup", when `i` is 2 and `j` is 3 (i.e. both Ls), you will exit the loop without comparing.  This means a non-palindromic even word will return true, when it ought to return false.

If you change the entire `where` clause to:

```
where (j - i > 0)
```

Your code will work for all cases.

Comment: opps i made an error the while statement is suppose to be this  >>

while (i != j && (j - 1) ! = 1) instead of while (i != j && (j - i) != !)    sry about that.. Thats probably the reason it wont compile

Comment: (j - 1 != 1), isn't that j != 2?

Comment: hmm can you explain what you know so far at least so i have bases of trying to figure out this block of code?  Thanks for all your help by the way!

Comment: @PHZEOXIDE.. that means `1-1 != 1` is equal to `1 != 1`. You actually said that?

Answer (score 1):

It's comparing the beginning of a String (position i) with the end of a String (position j), then traversing to the next pair of characters (i + 1, j - 1) until it reaches the middle of the String, to see if the String is a palindrome.